# Перегрузка операторов в PHP

Tags: php

Можно ли перегружать операторы в php для объектов, как в си?
Например, $obj1 - объект класс, $obj2 - объект класс.
и чтобы выполнялась операция $obj1+$obj2 так как я задам.
Если можно, то приведите, пож-та, пример.

Comment: Вот, но я еще не пробовал как работает
http://community.develstudio.ru/showthread.php/1647-ООП-Перегрузка-операторов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перегрузка операторов, аналогичная перегрузке в `C++` отсутствует в `php`.

И это не плюс и не минус, это просто некоторое решение, принятое, во время проектирования языка, более подробно можно почитать [**здесь.**](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=9331&edit=1)

---

Тем не менее, из правил есть исключения - например, можно добиться функциональности, похожей по своему смыслу на перегрузку, если речь идет про оператор `[]`. *Пример [здесь.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php)*

#### Update (из комментариев)

---

Если вы имеете ввиду **переопределить стандартные функции** *(т.к в классах все решается обычным полиморфизмом)*, то костыли существуют. Из известных мне способов - `Advanced PHP Debugger`, который поддерживает метод [`override_function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php) и `runkit`, который имеет метод [`runkit_function_redefine.`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php)

Я, к сожалению, не представляю себе, как работает второй из них, однако первый делает переподстановку символов заменяемых функций. *Аналогию можно провести, например, с использованием собственных аллокаторов в проектах `C++`.*

Comment: А возможно ли переопределение функций?

Comment: @mctrane Ответил вам апдейтом.